# Inserted string parsing in Groovy

Tags: string, parsing, groovy

I want to insert some variable into a string. And the name of the variable could also vary. Someting as:

```
"${${target}Class}."
```

But that is not allowed by syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Eval](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) class for these operations.

So, that line should look as:

```
"${Eval.me("${target}Class")}."
```